# How to set RecyclerView GridLayoutManager's max row

Tags: android, row, android-recyclerview

I have make a RecyclerView with using GridLayoutManager, now, I want to set the recycleView's max row, when rows exceed the max row, the recycler view will scroll.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 12));
```

Comment: set height of recyclerview....

Comment: I want not set the recycler view's height, because when the recyclerview's row less than max row, the height could wrap_content

Comment: there is no max raw consent inside recyclerview...you can achieve same with setting height...when recyclerview has max rows then height it will make it scrollable

Comment: If you want to load more data based on the max row then check the height of recycler view(better covers fullscreen) and when user tries to scroll then load data. But if you have less data such that it covers or less than height of recycler view then it would not provide scrolling

Comment: for example, i want the max row is 10, but when sometimes recycler view only has one row, i want the recyclerview only have one row's height.

Answer (score -2):

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this), size);
```

// size is no. of column

Comment: thanks your tip, i update the answer,  
I want not set the recycler view's height, because when the recyclerview's row less than max row, the height could wrap_content

Comment: you have to give height, instead of giving height, you can use android:maxHeight to set maximum height of recycler view